# select tag not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

Following is the code:

```
            <td><input class='datepicker' size=10 style='margin-left:auto;margin-right:1%;' id='endDate_0' placeholder='End Date' />
            </td>
            <td><select class='select_time' width='30%' size=5 id='startTime_0'></select>
            </td>
            <td><select class='select_time' width='30%' size=5 id='endTime_0'></select>
            </td>
```

css for select:

```
select{
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    width:100%;
}
```

js:

```
var select_time='<option value="0">0000 hrs</option>
<option value="100">0100 hrs</option>
<option value="200">0200 hrs</option>
<option value="300">0300 hrs</option>
<option value="400">0400 hrs</option>
<option value="500">0500 hrs</option>
<option value="600">0600 hrs</option>
<option value="700">0700 hrs</option>
<option value="800">0800 hrs</option>
<option value="900">0900 hrs</option>
<option value="1000">1000 hrs</option>
<option value="1100">1100 hrs</option>
<option selected value="1200">1200 hrs</option>
<option value="1300">1300 hrs</option>
<option value="1400">1400 hrs</option>
<option value="1500">1500 hrs</option>';

$('.select_time').html(select_time);
```

This is the output which i am getting[image]

I am unable to figure our why the select tag is not displayed properly,any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you create a fiddle here

Comment: Everything seems ok! What do you expect?

Comment: What's wrong with the output we see?

Comment: what browser are you using?  Kind of looks like Safari.  If so, Apple does some weird things where it will round up or down for styles applied to these type of controls.  If that isn't the case, note the select box and options do not allow for much customization with css in any browser..

Comment: @SuperHornet...i should be able to click and then select from the dropdown list,instead it shows me the list directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select box instead of list box then remove size from select tag.

```
<select class='select_time' width='30%' id='startTime_0'>
```